# How to decompress using JSZip

Tags: javascript, encoding, zip, compression

I trying to send large data from view page to the controller, I need to use one compression technique 
so i choose `JSZip` for compressing the data, I'am able to compress the data, but I'am unable to decompress the data using `JSZip` in view page(here compressed content will be returned from controller)
I've gone through [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/) but i have find no methods for decompression.

My compression code:

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("temp.txt", JSON.stringify(buffers[0]));
var content = zip.generate({ compression: "DEFLATE" });

// here I'am sending the 'content' to the controller
// and I' am receiving compressed content from controller like 'content' and trying to decompress it.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `load()` method: http://stuk.github.com/jszip/#doc_load_data_options

Comment: load is for creating a zip, not decompression. Am I wrong?